# .env Python syntax not properly recognized by IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

IntelliSense was working fine when I first started using Visual Studio Code for Python. However after I installed TypeScript IntelliSense seems to not recognize the syntax I used in .ENV.

For example if I input
`export TEST = "test"`
I get a warning from IntelliSense saying that
"export" is not definedPylance

I noticed on the bottom right the language mode was set to TypeScrip but the issue persisted when I switched it to Python. IntelliSense is working fine for other .py file though. I also tried open/reopen Visual Studio Code and open/reopen my project.

Comment: You might need to manually set the file type. VS might be trying to read your `.ENV`  file as a typescript file

Comment: Thank you Josh. I tried hitting the cmd+shift+p and searched for "Change Language   Mode" but it seems that it's already set to Python. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Do you add `export TEST = "test"` in the python file?

Comment: export TEST = "test" is what goest into the .env file

Answer (score 0):

Download the DOTENV extension package from vs code, immediately resolved my issue
[DOTENV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1LEl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32249397)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem for myself. You simply need to switch the language to 'Environment variable', if you click on the language on the bottom right then search it, it should come up, select it and instantly fixes the problem.